# Form submission controlled by function

Tags: forms, submit, form-submit

I've the current sumbit button in my code

```
<form role="form" action="" method="POST">
    ...
    <div class="box-footer">
        <button type="submit" onsubmit="submitForm()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </div>
    ...

@section('footer_js')
    <script>
        function submitForm() {return false;};
    </script>
@endsection
```

and I'd like to control the effective data submission by passing through the submitForm() function. The code I've pasted doesn't work since the submission always works. Maybe the attribute 'onsubmit' is not the right one to be used?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is in your function submitForm put e.preventDefault to prevent your form submitting server side. This would enable you to then do Javascript/ front-end validation:

```
function submitForm(e) 
{
   e.preventDefault();

   //Get user Values
   fname = $('#firstName').val(),
   email= $('#email').val(),

   if (validateName(fname) == true && validateEmail(email) == true)
   {

        $.ajax ({
        // you could then do an ajax call


   }


}

// This function will return a true value
// if your variable contains regex
function validateName(myname) {
    var re = /[a-z]/i;
    return re.test(myname);
}

function validateEmail(myemail) {
    var re = /[a-z]/i;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

If you had a form field called firstname and a form field called lastname you could check the values that the user enter against your criteria. If my example I am checking that the user's input is between A-Z. Once you have done that you can use ajax to send the user's input server side for further validation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It would be great if I could use ajax, but the page URL corresponds to an API call (this is why action="" method="POST") and must use that. I've tried to add the 'e.preventDefault();' code before the 'return false' line but there is no blocking action